# Array values are not getting properly in jquery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

i created this please view this in full screen and drag item b of last box to first box

[http://jsfiddle.net/StaHg/]

there are four kind of sortables with four different classes every class has elements with its data-item. i have allowed specific data-item values for specific width container in array name Data. its working for the first element in array.

For Example please drag item b of first container to last container

the container should accept those element which are allowed in array with there class name

Any ideas

Comment: please try to dragitem b of first container  to last container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're failing the minute the first item in the list doesn't match. You should only fail, once the loop has finished and all items don't match.

```
for( var j = 0; j <= Data[i].element.length; j++){
    if ( Data[i].element[j] == element){
        alert("they matched")
        return false;
    }
}

alert("Sorry The Specific item Cannot be placed here!");
$(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
return false
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StaHg/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your help i altered the method and achieved this but thank you for making me realize my mistake http://jsfiddle.net/StaHg/4/